# Can a Russian citizen enter Gibraltar with an EU residence permit?

Tags: uk, schengen, russian-citizens, gibraltar

According to some information on the [internet](http://www.gibraltarborder.gi/visa), a Russian passport holder can enter Gibraltar if they hold a valid Schengen visa.

**How is a German-issued EU residence permit (for work) treated by Gibraltar?** In the Schengen area, it behaves like a multi-entry Schengen visa, in that countries like Switzerland and Croatia accept it as equivalent (personal experience).

Answer (score 10):

I've contacted the Borders & Coastguard Agency of Gibraltar with exactly the case described above and have received the following answer:

> We do not accept residency cards issued outside of the United Kingdom
> unless they have been issued on the basis that the holder is a family
> member of an EU National. For us to accept the residency card it would
> need to state clearly that the holder is a family member.
>
> If the card has not been issued on this basis and you are a family
> member of an EU National and reside in an EU State together then we
> would accept an original marriage certificate, if the certificate is
> not in the English language then a copy must also be provided of a
> translation authorised by a notary.
>
> If none of the above apply to you or visitor and you are in fact a
> visa requiring national for Gibraltar then we would accept a UK
> Multiple entry 6 month Visitor visa or alternatively a UK Gibraltar
> Overseas territory visa.

From this answer, it seems that while most countries do consider an EU residence permit equivalent to a Schengen visa (if it was issued in a Schengen country), **this does not apply to Gibraltar**, even if the holder of the EU residence permit is a national of Russia, China, Morocco, Mongolia or India. **That means a separate UK or Gibraltar visa is required.**

(This of course creates the curious circumstance that a Russian national living in a Schengen country can invite and sponsor another Russian to get a Schengen visitor visa (which allows them to enter Gibraltar), but cannot enter it themselves.)

Comment: Since many Schengen countries use the type D visa as a de facto residence permit for stays 12 months or less, it also has the strange impact that if you reside in a Schengen country for 12 months or less, you can visit Gibraltar, but if you reside for a longer period and obviously therefore have a stronger tie to the country of residence, you are not let in without an additional visa. I agree, that it does not make much sense.

Comment: And in some Schengen states you may obtain a Schengen return visa as a resident inland in some circumstances...

Comment: Government policies are not required to make sense, and very frequently they do not. Governments do not operate by reason, but by force. But that is a topic for some other site.

Comment: A **D-Visa** is not a *Schengen Visa* but a **National Visa**. The Schengen Code does **not** define (or use) the term **Schengen Visa**. The Schengen Code defines 2 types of **short-stay visas**: *visa* type C and *airport transit visa* type A. Assume therefore that the Gibraltar authorities will assume that a **Schengen Visa** to be a **C-Visa** only.

Answer (score 2):

No, just as a Schengen resident permit does not exempt someone from the UK **Standard Visitor visa** requirement, the Gibraltar [Immigration, Asylum And Refugee Act, 1962-12](https://www.gibraltarlaws.gov.gi/legislations/immigration-asylum-and-refugee-act-178) forsee's no exception - despite the fact that certain holders (presently: nationals of Morocco, the People’s Republic of China, Mongolia, India or Russia) of a **valid multiple entry Schengen Visas** are exempt.

Only non-EEA national family members, that otherwise requires a visa, are exempt from a Gibraltar Visitor Visa.

---

#### [Immigration, Asylum And Refugee Act, 1962-12](https://www.gibraltarlaws.gov.gi/legislations/immigration-asylum-and-refugee-act-178)

- Commencement date: 2016-10-06 (latest version as of 2020-10-26)

> **Application: EEA Nationals and their family members**
> **3.**
> The provisions of sections 6, 7(2), 12(1), 14(1) and (2), 15 to 38, 52, 53 and 64 shall not apply to any person to whom, for the time being, sections 55A to 55X apply.
> ...
> **Entry into and exit from Gibraltar.**
> **11.**
> No person who seeks to enter or exit Gibraltar overland shall enter or exit other than–
>
> > (a) through the pedestrian or vehicular gates at the frontier, or
> > (b) through the commercial gates at the frontier at a time when it is open for authorized commercial traffic under the supervision and control of an immigration officer.
>
> **11A.**
> **(1)** The Government may direct the Principal Immigration Officer to waive the carrying out in circumstances described in such directions of any controls, powers or functions required or permitted under this Act on any persons or category of persons who enter or leave Gibraltar or who are in transit by land, sea or air through the airport to any other country specified in such direction.
> **(2)** A direction under sub-section (1) may include a waiver of the requirement to be in possession of a valid entry permit under section 12(1) and upon the issue of any such direction, the provisions of section 12(1) shall not apply to any person to whom the direction relates to the extent that it requires such person to be in possession of a valid entry permit.
> **(3)** Any direction issued under sub-section (1) may be revoked or modified by the Government at any time and from time to time and may impose restrictions on the period that such persons or categories of person may remain in Gibraltar.
> **(3A)**
> Any direction under subsection (1) which relates to a category of persons described by virtue of **their being nationals of particular countries who hold *valid multiple entry Schengen Visas*** shall be published in the Gazette.
> **(3B)**
> Any direction under subsection (1) to which subsection (3A) applies shall−
> (a) include a waiver under subsection (2) of the requirement to be in possession of a valid entry permit under section 12(1);
> (b) confirm that a waiver issued under subsection (2) does not entitle the holder to seek employment in Gibraltar or entitle him to have access to publicly funded benefits in Gibraltar;
> (c) specify a period that such a person is authorised to remain in Gibraltar which shall not exceed−
>
> > (i) 21 days; or
> > (ii) where the multiple entry Schengen Visa is due to expire before 21 days from the entry of the person into Gibraltar, the remainder of the period of validity of such multiple entry Schengen Visa less 7 days.
>
> ...
> **EEA Rights – Entry and Residence.**
> **Right of Entry to Gibraltar.**
> **55J**.
> (1) An EEA national shall be allowed to enter Gibraltar if he produces on arrival a valid passport or identity card issued by an EEA state.
> (2) A non-EEA national shall be allowed to enter Gibraltar if he is the family member of an EEA national, a family member who has retained the right of residence or a person with a permanent right of residence under section 55N if he produces on arrival–
>
> > (a) a valid passport; and
> > (b) an EEA family permit, a residence card or a permanent residence card.
>
> (3) An entry or exit stamp shall not be placed in the passport of a person allowed to enter Gibraltar under this section if-
>
> > (a) he is an EEA national; or
> > (b) he is a non-EEA national who produces a residence card or permanent residence card.
>
> ...
> **Entitlement to reside in Gibraltar for three months**
> **55L.**
> (1) The following persons are entitled to reside in Gibraltar for a period not exceeding three months from the date of entry into Gibraltar–
>
> > (a) an EEA national who holds a valid passport or identity card issued by an EEA state;
> > (b) a non-EEA national who-
> >
> > - (i) is a family member of an EEA national residing in Gibraltar under paragraph (a); and
> > - (ii) holds a valid passport.

---

**Note**:
A [Schengen visa](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/schengen_visa_en) is a short stay visa allowing its holder to circulate in the Schengen area, based on Article 2(5) (Type **A**) and Article 2(2) (Type **C**) of the Schengen Border Code.

A **national long-stay visa** (Type **D**, ANNEX VII (7 type of visa) of the Schengen Border Code) is not a **Schengen Visa**, but a **National Visa**.

---

**Sources**:

- [Immigration, Asylum And Refugee Act, 1962-12 [2016-10-06]](https://www.gibraltarlaws.gov.gi/legislations/immigration-asylum-and-refugee-act-178)

  - [Visas and Immigration](https://www.gibraltar.gov.gi/civil-status-registration-office/visas-and-immigration)

    - 2020-10-26: *This site is currently being revised*
  - [Gibraltar Borders & Coast Guard Agency - Visa & Entry](http://www.gibraltarborder.gi/visa)

Comment: I'm curious about the reason of downvote. Informative, official quote, (long but with) the most relevant part in bold.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's downvoted, but while nicely written, the answer just restated my question. I understand that Russian nationals can enter with a valid multiple entry Schengen visa - the question is: does Gibraltar treat an EU residence permit as a Schengen visa? After all, an EU residence permit automatically allows the holder to travel to any country that fully applies the Schengen agreement (https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm).

Comment: @ahemmetter The quoted law text **doesn't** meantion a Schengen resident permit at all, other than for family members. That is the reason why that text was added. If it was allowed, then it would have been listed as a reason of an exception. The answer states that Gibraltar rules are based in the UK rules (but with some exceptions), which you question did not state.

Comment: (-1) I think the provided answer misses the point of the question: Is an EU residence permit a form of EU multi-entry visa?

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk Since the Gibraltar law quoted lists what is acceptable and only lists residence cards/permits of EEA family members as acceptable, I would say the answer gives get the point quite correctly. Since the Gibraltar Border control acts soley on that law, only that law is relevant for them.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk Within the Schengen Area (to which Gibraltar has never belonged) a Schengen country resident permit is considered as a multi entry Schengen visa. There is no such thing as a **EU resident permit**.

Comment: @ahemmetter From your given source: *If you have a valid residence permit from one of those **Schengen countries**, it is equivalent to a visa. You may need a **national visa** to visit non-Schengen countries*. Neither the UK or Gibraltar are a Schengen country.

Comment: @ahemmetter I just had a spin through Gibraltar's legislation site, and I can only agree with the conclusion in this answer: the legislation and the related "directions" mention only multiple-entry Schengen visas. Now it's possible that Gibraltar's authorities think that the phrase so obviously includes residence permits that nobody ever thought to mention them explicitly, in which case you would be admitted with your residence permit.  But short of attempting this yourself, all you can do, it seems, is to hope that someone who has will post an answer to this question.

Comment: @phoog The doubt is justified. The information page from the Bulgarian MFA also only mention that holders of Schengen visa may enter Bulgaria, when they in reality mean visa and residence permit holders. In many Schengen countries, there is no practical difference between a type D visa and a residence permit and I would not find it strange if Gibraltan authorities include residence permits in a generic meaning of the word 'visa'. https://www.mfa.bg/en/services-travel/consular-services/travel-bulgaria/visa-bulgaria

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I downvoted, because as OP points out, this is just a very verbose reiteration of what was already stated and what OP is aware of. It does not really answer the question asked.

Comment: @phoog When in doubt, they probably follow the UK rules (which doesn't make an exception). Note also that their Schengen Visa rule is **only** for 5 nationalities (not everyone). For a day visitor they may not care, but that should not be assumed to be the rule. The answer states, whereas the question does not. Comparing with Bulgaria is therefore should be replaced with UK.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Well I would find it strange, since Gibraltar is a [British Overseas Territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Overseas_Territories) and therefore more likly to follow UK immigration rules that doesn't excempt (as stated in the answer - but not in the question) Schengen resident permit holders from Standard Visitor Visa requirements.

Comment: @MarkJohnson My question is specifically about Russian citizens, who I am aware of that they are in this "special" group for which an exception is granted.

Comment: @ahemmetter But neither the relevent Gibraltar law or it government site state that this also applies to Schengen country resident permits. (Why not, is a valid question). Any official statement would be based on that law. No other answer can be given based on the legal text. Anything else would be speculation (such as: because Bulgaria does it that way, Gibraltar will likely do so also).

Comment: @ahemmetter It would seem then, from your self supplied answer, that my answer was correct.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Had Gibraltar followed UK immigration rules, they would not have let in any Schengen visa holders just based on the Schengen visa, so that argument is moot. There is obviously a difference between Gibraltarian and UK immigration law. You pointed that difference out yourself.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbo Yes and? It is common knowledge that British Overseas Territories immigration rules are **based** on UK rules. And that what my answers states, with quotes from the relevant law showing that residence permit are not included within those exceptions. Your suggestion about Bulgaria was unrealistic from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

**Today:** A German residence permit will not be enough to enter Gibraltar for a Russian citizen. In normal circumstances, a visa is needed to access Gibraltar unless the Russian citizen holds a EU family permit.

**Covid-19 situation.** Due to Covid situation in Spain only EU citizens or holders of EU Family permit can access Gibraltar via the Spanish border. Citizens that hold a EU family permit can also access it.
https://makespain.com/gibraltar-city-guide/

Due to COVID-19 no access was possible through Spain till July unless the person accessing Gibraltar held a working permission (a working contract) in Gibraltar. Due to the evolution of the Covid-measures in all regions in Spain, this restriction could be back in place. Please note this does not depend on Gibraltar authorities only.

**Brexit** also adds complexity. It is not clear if Gibraltar will be part of Schengen after Brexit. Gibraltar has requested this. This could imply a different reality to a Russian citizen with working permission in Germany but it is so far unclear
https://www.etiasvisa.com/etias-news/etias-gibraltar

Comment: It should be noted that [ETIAS - Visa Waver for Europe](https://www.etiasvisa.com) is **not** an official EU site (See the *Disclaimer* at the bottom of each page). It is *owned and operated by the Company stated in the Terms and Conditions section of this website*. I could not find any **Terms and Conditions section** which stated the name or address of the Company on that website.